# Calling a Directive from another Directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Please consider this [tryout on Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/OHX5euXzj2wb1knKhtnN?p=preview).

I have a simple set up:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
      <parent-directive></parent-directive>
      <child-directive></child-directive>
    </div>
</body>
```

With the parent directive defined like:

```
app.directive("parentDirective", [
    "$compile",
    function (
        $compile) {
        return {
            scope: {
                person: "="
            },
            restrict: "E",
            template: "<h3>I'm a parent</h3>",
            controller: [
                "$scope",
                function ($scope) {
                    // --- PRIVATE --- //

                    var self = {};

                    $scope.ClickMe = function() {
                      alert('Parent clicked');
                    };
                }],
            link: function ($scope, $elem, $attrs) {
            }
        };
    }]);
```

And child directive defined like:

```
app.directive("childDirective", [
    "$compile",
    function (
        $compile) {
        return {
            scope: {
                person: "="
            },
            restrict: "E",
            require: "^?parentDirective",
            template: "<h3>I'm a child, click <button ng-click='ClickMe()'>here</button></h3>",
            controller: [
                "$scope",
                function ($scope) {
                    // --- PRIVATE --- //

                    var self = {};

                    $scope.ClickMe = function() {
                      alert('child clicked');
                      $scope.parentDirective.ClickMe();
                    };
                }],
            link: function ($scope, $elem, $attrs) {
            }
        };
    }]);
```

The `child` click is handled, but the click defined on the `parent', returns undefined:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'ClickMe' of undefined

*looking at the console.*

Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: Hi @Spikee you should check out the link http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/07/07/practical-guide-to-prelink-postlink-and-controller-methods-of-angular-directives/

Answer (score 1):

> Any idea what's going wrong?

1. You **cannot** `require` a sibling directive.
2. The required directives controller methods **dont** get exposed automagically onto your scope.
3. You should expose methods **on the controller itself**, not on the assigned `$scope`.

---

You can `require` a directive that is defined *on the same element* as the requiring directive, **or** on *a parent element.*

```
<child-directive parent-directive></child-directive>

<parent-directive>
  <child-directive></child-directive>
</parent-directive>
```

---

When you `require` the controller (aka. exposed API) of another directive, it doesn't  magically end up on the $scope of the requiring directive.

It does however end up in your `link` function as the fourth argument.

Like so:

```
.directive('child', function () {
  return {
    require: '?^parentDirective',
    link: function (scope, el, attrs, parentDirectiveController) {
      scope.clickMe = function () {
        parentDirectiveController.clickMe();
      };
    }
  };
});
```

---

Expose the methods you want available in other directives onto `this` instead of $scope, as the $scope way of doing it won't work the way you intend it to when you have isolated scopes.

```
.directive('parent', 
  controller: function () {
    this.clickMe = function () {};
  }
}
```

---

To get your example working;

```
<parent>
  <child></child>
</parent>
```

---

```
.directive('parent', function () {
  return {
    controller: function () {
      this.clickMe = function () {};
    }
  };
}

.directive('child', function () {
  return {
    require: '^?parent',
    link: function (scope, el, attrs, parentCtrl) {
      scope.clickMe = function () {
        parentCtrl.clickMe();
      };
    } 
  };
});
```

---

Simplified (& working) version of your plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/nao4EvbptQm7gDKkmZS2?p=preview

Comment: This is a great answer and is specific to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Put your child directive in your parent directive template. Then use $scope.$parent.ClickMe(). Here's what it would look like.

Simple setup:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <parent-directive></parent-directive>
    </div>
</body>
```

Parent directive:

```
app.directive("parentDirective", [
    function () {
        return {
            scope: {},
            restrict: "E",
            template: "<h3>I'm a parent</h3><child-directive></child-directive>",
            controller: [
                "$scope",
                function ($scope) {
                    $scope.ClickMe = function() {
                        alert('Parent clicked');
                    };
                }
            ]
        };
    }
]);
```

Child directive:

```
app.directive("childDirective", [
    function () {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            template: "<h3>I'm a child, click <button ng-click='ClickMe()'>here</button></h3>",
            controller: [
                "$scope",
                function ($scope) {
                    $scope.ClickMe = function() {
                        alert('child clicked');
                        $scope.$parent.ClickMe();
                    };
                }
            ]
        };
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be thinking about your problem a little differently but I would take a look at $broadcast. The idea is you can broadcast an event and have "n" number of directives in your case listening for that event.

http://plnkr.co/edit/wBmX2TvC3yMXwItfxkgl

brodcast:

```
$scope.ClickMe = function() {
                  alert('child clicked');
                  $rootScope.$broadcast('child-click');;
                };
```

listen:

```
$scope.$on('child-click', function (event, args) {
                    alert('Parent clicked');
                });
```